# MySQL Select Date Between Two Columns

Tags: php, mysql

```
id   date_in       date_out      room_count
 1   [2021-08-15]  [2021-08-18]  [4]
 2   [2021-08-15]  [2021-08-19]  [1]
 3   [2021-08-19]  [2021-08-22]  [1]
 4   [2021-08-19]  [2021-08-23]  [1]
 5   [2021-08-22]  [2021-08-25]  [1]
 6   [2021-08-22]  [2021-08-25]  [2]
 7   [2021-08-23]  [2021-08-24]  [3]
 8   [2021-08-23]  [2021-08-28]  [6]
```

I have such data in the database and I want to search between these dates, for example, on the 19th and 31th of the month

```
$in = '2021-08-19';

$out = '2021-08-31';


SELECT COUNT(id), SUM(room_count) FROM table_name WHERE ( ('$in' BETWEEN date_in AND DATE_ADD(date_out, INTERVAL -1 DAY)) OR ('$out' BETWEEN DATE_ADD(date_in, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND date_out) )
```

Since I chose between 19 and 31, nothing comes back to me. but the sum of the number of rooms I want

how to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by *I want to search between these dates*? Edit your question and explain what you want.

Comment: I want the sum of the room numbers of the data between the 19th and 31st of the month I think it's clear

Comment: Count and Sum are aggregate functions I wouldn't suggest you to use both of them at the same time if you don't know how aggregate functions work. Use sum function in a nested query. Also I suggest you to remove everything after where statement and use like where date_in > xxx and date_out < xxx

Comment: @erman999 I'm using count elsewhere. Right now I need SUM(room_count) that is the sum of the numbers in the rooms between the dates.

Comment: I got what you mean. It's very easy. I can write that query for you half hour later I am on the way now :)

Comment: ok i will be waiting for your reply thanks

Comment: What is the number room_count in your sample data? Is it the number of free rooms in that period? Is it the number of occupied rooms in that period?

Comment: yes, the number of occupied rooms between those dates

Comment: And when you search with $in = '2021-08-19' and $out = '2021-08-31' what do you expect? The number of free rooms or the number of occupied rooms in that period?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Similiar to the comments between you and erman9999.
This is a pretty simple WHERE-clause to check if two conditions are true.

```
SELECT 
SUM(room_count)
FROM rooms
WHERE date_in >= '2021-08-19' AND date_out <= '2021-08-31'
```

Result:
SUM(room_count) = 14

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0e03d0aaed9d468cae8d55ef22834f6e)

Comment: that's fine, but typing 20 instead of 31 returns null

Comment: according to your provided data and question, there is no room where someone stayed in starting 2021-08-19 and left it on or before the 20.

Comment: this is a hotel room simulation, it should show me the rest except the rooms that are occupied between 19 and 20

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your query correct, you want to get total rooms occupied between the given dates.

```
SELECT
    sum(t.room_count) AS 'room_count'
FROM
    temp t
WHERE
    (t.date_in >= '2021-08-19'
        AND t.date_in <= '2021-08-31')
    OR (t.date_out >= '2021-08-19'
        AND t.date_out <= '2021-08-31');
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5caa90d/7)